# Need to use an object to filter with lodash and include a between condition

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, lodash

We made a videogame database and we need to filter people by game and rank. The structure of this object is as follows:

```
[{
    "key": 86,
    "position": [
      40.369,
      -3.5419
    ],
    "info": {
      "gamesplaying": [
        {
          "gameid": 2,
          "rankid": 8
        },
        {
          "gameid": 4,
          "rankid": 8
        },
        {
          "gameid": 5,
          "rankid": 14
        }
      ],
      "city": "Kersey",
      "age": 42,
      "name": "Fisher Hayden",
      "id": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "key": 87,
    "position": [
      40.554,
      -3.7578
    ],
    "info": {
      "gamesplaying": [
        {
          "gameid": 2,
          "rankid": 2
        }
      ],
      "city": "Ahwahnee",
      "age": 24,
      "name": "Aurora Rivers",
      "id": 35
    }
  }]
```

We need to perform a filter by game id and rank id, and it seems like _.filter helps us when using an object as filter, instead of a function. This does not mind the number of elements in the gamesplaying array or the order the are in, so its perfect! The performance is way better than a few nested for loops, so we would love to keep this function.

Our problem is that we now added an age filter. So we do not need an exact age, but ages between 2 values.

The function looks like this right now:

```
 let markers = this.props.markers;

    if(this.state.rankidFilter > 0 || this.state.gameidFilter > 0 || this.state.minAgeFilter > 0 || this.state.maxAgeFilter > 0) {

      let gameFilters = {};
      if (this.state.gameidFilter > 0) gameFilters = {...gameFilters, gameid: parseInt(this.state.gameidFilter, 10)};
      if (this.state.rankidFilter > 0) gameFilters = {...gameFilters, rankid: parseInt(this.state.rankidFilter, 10)};

      let newMarkers =_.filter(this.props.markers, {info: {gamesplaying: [gameFilters]}});

      markers = newMarkers;
    }
```

We tried a few things to add in that filter object functions or conditions for the age property so the value is between 2 numbers but we do not find the correct way of doing so.

Please help, we would like to keep the _.filter function. Thanks in advance

EDIT: an object like {info: {gamesplaying: [{gameid: parseInt(this.state.gameidFilter, 10), rankid: parseInt(this.state.rankidFilter, 10)}]}, age: _.between(20, 55)} to take into account a range of ages in that value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to perform this with a single lodash filter rather than chaining more than one filter, you could do something like this, using a function rather than an object for the second `_.filter` argument:

```
markers = _.filter(markers, o =>
    (!this.state.minAgeFilter || (o.info.age >= this.state.minAgeFilter))
        && (!this.state.maxAgeFilter || (o.info.age <= this.state.maxAgeFilter))
        && (!this.state.gameidFilter || _.find(o.info.gamesplaying, { gameid: this.state.gameidFilter }))
        && (!this.state.rankidFilter || _.find(o.info.gamesplaying, { rankid: this.state.rankidFilter })));
```

This combines your `> 0` checks directly into the filter expression. For each potential filter in `this.state`, the `!this.state.fooFilter ||` part of the line short-circuits the expression if the filter is falsy (null, non-existent, or 0). If the fooFilter value is greater than 0, then the second half of the line is evaluated. In the case of the age filters we compare `>=` or `<=` accordingly, and in the case of the gameid and rankid filters, we use `_.find` to check if an object with the matching id exists in the array. Note that these joined `&&` expressions are ordered from lower evaluation cost to higher (putting the `_.find` calls later in the list) so that short-circuit evaluation might save us some time.

A couple notes about your original code:

- I'm not sure why your code above is performing `parseInt` on the idfilter numbers after you've already directly compared them to 0 in the if condition above it.
- You don't need the temporary variable `newMarkers` to store the value with the one-line lodash filter approach.

*Edited to add*: Jorge rightfully points out that my `_.find` clauses will make the filter return any object that contains individual games with the gameid and rankid, not necessarily in the same game. We can combine these into a single find in various ways. Here's one approach:

```
const gameFilter = {};
if (this.state.gameidFilter) {
    gameFilter.gameid = this.state.gameidFilter;
}
if (this.state.rankidFilter) {
    gameFilter.rankid = this.state.rankidFilter;
}

markers = _.filter(markers, o =>
    (!this.state.minAgeFilter || (o.info.age >= this.state.minAgeFilter))
        && (!this.state.maxAgeFilter || (o.info.age <= this.state.maxAgeFilter))
        && (_.size(gameFilter) === 0 || _.find(o.info.gamesplaying, gameFilter)));
```

In the case that both a gameidFilter and rankidFilter are provided, the find will only return a truthy value (the found object) if there is a game in the gamesplaying array with both the correct gameid and correct rankid. Otherwise the find will return the falsy `undefined`, causing the `_.filter` expression to evaluate to `false`.

Comment: This is my first try at lodash :P, so a lot of messy stuff is there from today... and I need to do a lot of clean up after testing, can't even remember why that parse is there, I think is because some ESLint warning a few hours ago. So 2 things, first, thanks for this solution since is the way I want to go. The only correction I need to do is that the rankid and the gamid need to be in the same object as the filter values. Your solution finds either one in different objects in the array. Thank you very much though since it does what I want with the age. Would you recommend nested _.filter s?

Comment: Excellent point! I have updated the answer to add another approach which corrects the issue you've raised. This could also be accomplished other ways, such as with nested or chained filters, and those might be more human-readable.

Comment: Ok, so is it only for readability, or the nested filter example would perform better. In this case, we need this part of the code to be as fast as possible, Hahaha, just read your edit and it's the same approach I did when applying conditional filtering for those 2 conditions. So seems I am structuring correctly, Thanks for the help!

Comment: I honestly do not worry about JavaScript optimization that deeply, so I'm not the best person to answer the performance question... but speaking very generally, I expect short-circuit evaluation expressions to be faster than multiple function calls.